# Conteo de dias del año

Tags: c#, time, real-time

Conocen algun metodo o herramienta de visual studio c# que cuente los dias del año incluyendo bisiestos

> Necesito eso para poder realizar las demas funciones de la app

Comment: ¿A que te referis con que cuente los dias del año? ¿A que diga si el año tiene 365 o 366 dias?

Comment: Sí, se llama `System.DateTime`, no hace exactamente lo que quieres, pero te sirve.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno es un poco sencillo un año tiene 365 pero si febrero tiene 28 dias son 366 
entonces solo usa una funcion que te regrese si un año es bisiesto, si lo es tiene 366 sino son 365 aqui un ejemplo:

```
if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(fecha)) 
{
   //hacer algo
}
else
{
  // hacer algo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso es lo puedes lograr obteniendo la diferencia entre dos fechas.

Le restas una fecha futura a la fecha actual y el resultado es la cantidad de tiempo de diferencia entre esas dos fechas.

Echale un ojo a la documentacion de la estructura DateTime: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Y a la documentacion de la estructura TimeSpan:https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx